# PHP Mysql Relations

Tags: php, mysql, subquery

```
id  message     round   date            user_id     video_id
1   TextMsg     1       2018-01-26      1           1
2   TextMsg     1       2018-01-26      2           1
3   TextMsg     2       2018-01-26      2           6
```

I have this table 'messages 'on my Mysql database, 
with relations user_id to my users table and video_id to my videos table
using php how can I make a loop that shows
the messages like a chat. 
All the messages related to the video

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE $id = videos.id // I doubt
```

then

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE round = 1 // need to make the rounds as tabs
```

then

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = id
```

I'm completely lost, any help would be awesome,
Appreciate.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM messages WHERE video_id = YOUR_ID`

Comment: Can you describe to what the `user_id` and `video_id` columns correspond?  What does your expected output look like?

Comment: whats the purpose of round id in the table.?

Comment: I'm working in a platform to help control the amends of our video projects,
So we have the first round of amends. Somehow I have to enable the first round of comments to the client and when we make all the changes the client wants I have to enable a second round of comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to do a left join.

`SELECT * FROM messages 
LEFT JOIN videos ON videos.id=messages.video_id
LEFT JOIN users ON users.id=messages.user_id
WHERE video_id={$id} GROUP BY rounds ORDER BY date DESC`

Take note of the duplicate columns, rename if necessary.